# ArgumentException not found in Dictionary ContainsKey check

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, collections, dictionary

I have code like this:

```
if (!likeDict.ContainsKey(s))
{
    likeDict.Add(s, s);
}
```

And I keep getting an error that an item with the same key has already been added. I thought ContainsKey is the check for this and that is where the error is occuriing, not at the add line. Am I misinterpreting ContainsKey?

Comment: Maybe, I dunno though....I guess I can do a try catch to catch the exception

Comment: Is it ok when the value is overwritten if the key already exists? Then just use `likeDict[s]=s`.

Comment: What is prompting you to add this entry? How likely is it in your ASP.NET environment that two or more requests would prompt this addition in a small window of time? If this is a cached dictionary that, for example, would rapidly get filled via user activity after the app starts and then eventually stay somewhat stagnant, you could see many collisions early. In this hypothetical scenario, maybe you should aggressively populate the dictionary *once* and leave it alone.

Comment: How is declared this dictionary? What is the datatype of the key and which type is s?

Comment: its string, string for the dictionary and s is also a string. It's weird as it adds my s = "Debt" and then tries to add s = "Debt" again

Comment: Is it `static` (or cached) as Anthony presumed? Give us more context.

Comment: Not related to the exception, but why are you adding `s` as both key and value?  Seems like you'd be better off using `List<string>`, then.

Comment: Its declared like this: Dictionary<string, string> likeDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Comment: Which method is this in? Maybe that's executed twice? Would need more context...

Comment: Turns out you guys were all right. You needed more context as the parameters.Add for SQL injections was causing the issue in the lines above. Thx.

Comment: @zimdanen: More appropriate would be a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using the dictionary in a multithreaded scenario. If this is the case, you can switch to using [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) which provides the following [`TryAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291.aspx) method:

```
bool added = likeDict.TryAdd(s, s);
```

If you are using this dictionary as a cache for equivalent objects, you could also use the [`GetOrAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676.aspx) method:

```
var value = likeDict.GetOrAdd(s, s);
bool added = object.ReferenceEquals(value, s);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error could happen if this is static/shared resource (as pointed in previous comments). In this case, apply [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) statement.

Hope this will help. My best, AB